# How to properly load type Int from Coq.ZArith.Int?

Tags: coq

I'm new to coq and I am trying to use the "int" type from ZArith.Int but coq cannot find it.

```
Require Export ZArith Int.
Open Scope Int_scope.
```

when I use "int" in my definitions such as (... -> int -> ...), coq cannot find it. How can I properly load it along with the library's operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That library actually formalizes an abstract module of integers, that can be later instantiated with a concrete implementation. In Coq, the implementation of integers from the standard library is called `Z`. There's an instance of the `Int` module type in terms of `Z` defined in that library, called `Z_as_Int`; to use the definitions available there with Z, you just need to refer to them prefixed by the module name, e.g. `Z_as_Int._0`. However, given that most theorems are proven directly over `Z`, without relying on the interface defined in `Int`, it is probably better to just use `Z` directly.

Comment: He could also `Import Z_as_Int` to get rid of the prefix.